# InvalidArgumentException: Action App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@store not defined

Tags: laravel, api, unit-testing, controller, laravel-8

I'm new to unit Testing and I'm using Laravel 8 ,

I get always this error :

```
InvalidArgumentException: Action App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@store not defined.
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test case you need to add `\` before your namespace to get the absolute path

```
$response = $this->postJson(action('\App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@store'), [
   'doAssigned' => false,
   'doValidate' => false,
]);
```

Also, you can call `action` to the controller without namespace like `action('OrderController@store')`

Comment: Thank you , but after making the changes  I got an error in : the line ` $response->assertJsonPath('status', 'draft');` the error is that "Invalid JSON was returned from the route."

Comment: I don't see any JSON with `status:draft` returned from your controller method, you can do  `$this->postJson(...)->dump()`  to see the what returned.

Comment: after addind the  `dump()` I get the `Error: Call to a member function dump() on string` , my main goal is to test that I get `status = 'draft'`  when my   ` doAssigned' => false`,  and  `doValidate' => false`,

Comment: In your controller you need to return `return response()->json(['order' => $newOrder, 'status' => 'draft']);`

Comment: In my controller I'm not sure If I can set the 'status' to 'draft' because the status can be 'draft' or 'pending' depending on the dovalidate , and doAssigned , In my test I want to test only the case when  doValidate and doAssigned are set to false @mmabdelgawad .

Comment: I suggest adding a new question with the new issue and explain what you need and mark this answer as accepted for future references.